# How to optimise WiFi and ZigBee Coexistence

Tags: smart-home, wifi, zigbee

Assuming I'm not ready to give up 2.4 GHz wifi just yet, and I'm mostly immune to interference from nearby installations (i.e. I have control of any relevant configurations), what should I be doing to minimise disruptive interference between the different unlicensed installations?

I have at least ZigBee, BLE and WiFi all sharing the 2.4 GHz band (and the microwave doing it's best to block any signals from the oven - but it's too late to re-site these)